# LDAP Active Directory authentication problem using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

I have implemented authentication against the forsumsys.com LDAP test server successfully, using Spring Boot 2.7.0. But when I try to have the same implementation running against my company's AD server, I get this exception:

```java
2022-06-01 14:54:15.505 DEBUG 6968 --- [nio-9080-exec-8] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Failed to bind with any user DNs [sAMAccountName=my-username]
2022-06-01 14:54:15.576 DEBUG 6968 --- [nio-9080-exec-8] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Found DN: CN=My Full Name,OU=Users,OU=Group4,OU=Group3,OU=Group2,OU=Group1,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com
2022-06-01 14:54:15.739 DEBUG 6968 --- [nio-9080-exec-8] o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch      : Found user 'my-username', with FilterBasedLdapUserSearch [searchFilter=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0})); searchBase=DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com; scope=subtree; searchTimeLimit=0; derefLinkFlag=false ]
2022-06-01 14:54:15.739 DEBUG 6968 --- [nio-9080-exec-8] o.s.s.l.u.LdapUserDetailsMapper          : Mapping user details from context with DN CN=My Full Name,OU=Users,OU=Group4,OU=Group3,OU=Group2,OU=Group1,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com
...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:289) ~[spring-security-crypto-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:237) ~[spring-security-crypto-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$LazyPasswordEncoder.matches(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:599) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:76) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
```

This is what I have on my application.yml

```
ldap:
  urls: ldap://ldaphost:389/
  base:
    dn: DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com
  username: ldap_bind_username
  password: ldap_bind_password
  user:
    dn:
      #pattern: sAMAccountName={0},OU=Users,OU=Group4,OU=Group3,OU=Group2,OU=Group1
      pattern: sAMAccountName={0}
  search:
    filter: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))
```

This is the relevant part of my LdapConfig class

```java
/**
 * 
 */
package xyz;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

...

/**
 * Configures the HTTP Security of the application, and the LDAP
 * authentication manager.
 * 
 * @author  myself
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class LdapSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrls;

    @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
    private String ldapBaseDn;

    @Value("${ldap.search.filter}")
    private String ldapSearchFilter;

    @Value("${ldap.username}")
    private String ldapSecurityPrincipal;

    @Value("${ldap.password}")
    private String ldapPrincipalPassword;

    @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
    private String ldapUserDnPattern;
    
    @Value("${cors.allowedOrigins}")
    private List<String> corsAllowedOrigins;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
        .cors(withDefaults())   // Activates CORS support via CORS configuration (see below)
        .csrf()                 // Disable CSRF protection, since we implement a stateless 
            .disable()          // session management
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()   // Allow unauthenticated requests to /authenticate
            .anyRequest().authenticated()               // Forbid unauthenticated requests everywhere else
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()  // Place the JWT Filter before user/pw authentication filter, to ensure it gets called before any endpoint
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(
            (request, response, ex) -> {
                response.sendError(
                    HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                    ex.getMessage()
                );
            }
        );
    }
    
    /**
     * Configures the LDAP authentication manager, and set it in the AuthenticationManagerBuilder.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                .url(ldapUrls + ldapBaseDn)
                .managerDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal)
                .managerPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword)
            .and()
                .userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern)
            .and()
                .userDetailsService(ldapUserDetailsService())
        ;
    }

    
    /**
     * CORS configuration.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        
        // The URLs for which cross-origin requests are allowed
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(corsAllowedOrigins);
        
        // List of allowed HTTP verbs
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        
        // Allowing all headers for now - ideally this should be narrowed 
        // down to the strictly necessary
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        
        // Sets the CORS configuration to all url mappings
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource(); source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        
        return source; 
    }
    
    @Bean
    AppAuthenticationSuccessHandler appAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new AppAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }
    
    @Bean
    AppAuthenticationFailureHandler appAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new AppAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    /**
     * Declares and configures an LdapUserDetailsService bean, which will be
     * used to e.g. retrieve the user details by username from the LDAP tree. 
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public LdapUserDetailsService ldapUserDetailsService() {
        
        LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        ldapContextSource.setUrl(ldapUrls);
        ldapContextSource.setUserDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal);
        ldapContextSource.setPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword);
        ldapContextSource.setReferral("follow");
        ldapContextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        
        return new LdapUserDetailsService(
                    new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(ldapBaseDn,
                                                  ldapSearchFilter, 
                                                  ldapContextSource)
                    );
    }
}
```

And this is what I found:

This is the method in the DAOAuthenticationProvider which checks if the inputed password matches the user password in AD

```java
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages
                    .getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }
        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        if (!this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) { // PROBLEM HERE!!!
            this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages
                    .getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }
    }
```

The problem is that *userDetails.getPassword()* is null. And therefore, the encoded password prefix (which should have been returned from the AD?) which would help to find an appropriate PasswordEncoder can't be found, which originates the error.

One thing I noted is that, when I try to authenticate against the *forumsys.com* ldap test server, I have no issues and the *userDetails.getPassword()* call does retrieve a value, instead of null.

What could I be doing wrong? I have spent far more time going around this then I would like to admit :-) Would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: AD will not send back the users cleartext password, nor should it. Why don't you trust the authentication decision made by AD in the first place?

Comment: Hi Mathias. I am not expecting to receive the password in clear text. But note that the *DAOAuthenticationProvider* that I refer to above is a spring class. And it does expect a hashed password, which it seems will use, together with a predefined password encoder, to compare against the password entered by the user.

Comment: AD isn't gonna do that either, by design - essentially in order to keep them where they belong: _on the authentication server_ :) If you don't trust AD = don't use AD

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But, as I mentioned, I am trying to connect to AD with spring boot, and the spring boot class I mentioned is where that password check is made. I am not very familiar with AD, obviously. Your answer may help in the sense that it may indicate that I cannot use the same spring boot configuration that I successfully used to authenticate against the forumsys.com ldap server, against AD. So maybe someone else could give me a hint about how to connect to AD using spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

The [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/ldap.html#_active_directory) says "Active Directory supports its own non-standard authentication options, and the normal usage pattern does not fit too cleanly with the standard LdapAuthenticationProvider" and goes on recommend using ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider which I see is already in your import.

There is an [example on medium.com](https://hpratap.medium.com/configure-windows-active-directory-authentication-using-spring-security-in-a-spring-boot-480c31ef63c6) which shows using this.

if you replace your method protected void configure() with the following, it should work.

```
    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryAuthenticationManager() {
        return new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(myDomain, ldapUrl);
    }
```